# LC-3 Analyzing given piece of text

Tags: lc3

How do I store a given piece of text in memory? For example:

“I had a dream last night that a man had me over for dinner. I said that I did not like what we had, but he did not mind.”

I want to store each word in a separate memory location.

Eventually I want to output the number of characters in each word.

Answer (score 0):

In LC3 (and in general) you will want to store each letter at a separate memory location.

Your LC3 program needs to create a label at a location in memory with enough space to store all of these characters. Call this your FIRST_CHARACTER label.

If you need to find each "word" individually after you read in an arbitrary sentence, you may also need to also store offset "distance" in character from the start of FIRST_CHARACTER.  You would have an offset value stored in memory for each word you read.  You would store these values starting at some other tag in memory called OFFSET_COUNTS.  So the first word would always start at location FIRST_CHARACTER.  The second word would start at location FIRST_CHARACTER + (the value found at OFFSET_COUNTS+1), etc.

There are other approaches, but if this is what you need to do, you will need to have some way of finding each word in memory after the fact.

Another approach could be to just search through the entire string stored at FIRST_CHARACTER and count  SPACES in the original string until you get to the start of the first word you are looking for.

Have a look at the lc3tutor.org "get a line" code sample for more concise examples of how to store a string in memory if you need that.

Good luck!

Jeff